# a general measure of data-set imbalance

Tags: machine-learning, skewness, unbalanced-classes

I am working on thousands of datasets. Many of them are "unbalanced"; either a multi-class list with highly skewed distribution (For example, three categories with the ratio of 3500:300:4 samples) or a continuous number with skewed distribution.
I am looking for some metric that can say "**How badly unbalanced**" the dataset is. Is there such a metric?

Eventually, I want to score these datasets according to their balanced metric and provide a different balancing/ machine learning solution for each of them.
I prefer a python solution if it exists.

Comment: If you use R, you can use the diversity() function in the 'vegan' package to calculate the Shannon-Weaver index. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/2.4-2/topics/diversity

Comment: It's not clear why you chose the word _balance_ as if imbalance is a bad thing.  If you use a method that depends on the amount of balance in levels of $Y$, switch to another method.

Comment: mild ---> 20-40% of the data set
Moderate ---> 1-20% of the data set
Extreme ---> <1% of the data set     
https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/data-prep/construct/sampling-splitting/imbalanced-data

Comment: I opine that many of the answers below are too fancy.  If we want a simple scalar to indicate how imbalanced a multi-classed dataset is, just report the **percent in the minority class**.  Do not represent it as a ratio-- this gets highly non-linear and doesn't generalize to multi-class problems.  

A perfectly balanced binary-class dataset would be 50%.   If we have 100 classes that are perfectly balanced, we'd expect 1% for the minority class, which is already hard; but if the minority class in this case were 0.001% we know it's even more imbalanced; also report the number in the minority.

Comment: To follow up on @FrankHarrell's point, *why* do you want to have a balanced machine learning solution?  Generally imbalance is not itself a problem, and the machine learning (i.e. statistical) model will be giving a near-optimal solution for the learning task *as posed* (if applied correctly).  If there is a good reason for balancing, it is because the misclassification costs are not equal, and the amount re-weighting/resampling has little or nothing to do with the degree of imbalance.  The key is to work out what you really want the model to do.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use the **Shannon entropy** to measure **balance**.

On a data set of $n$ instances, if you have $k$ classes of size $c_i$ you can compute entropy as follows:
$$ H = -\sum_{ i = 1}^k \frac{c_i}{n} \log{ \frac{c_i}{n}}. $$

This is equal to:

- $0$ when there is one single class. In other words, it tends to $0$ when your data set is very unbalanced
- $\log{k}$ when all your classes are balanced of the same size $\frac{n}{k}$

Therefore, you could use the following measure of **Balance** for a data set:
$$ \mbox{Balance} = \frac{H}{\log{k}} = \frac{-\sum_{ i = 1}^k \frac{c_i}{n} \log{ \frac{c_i}{n}}.  } {\log{k}} $$
which is equal to:

- $0$ for an unbalanced data set
- $1$ for a balanced data set

Comment: Note that any logarithm base is fine because the normalization makes the formula invariant to the base.

Comment: @Simone, do you know if this balance equation is a standard balance measure in the literature?

Comment: Not in particular. I think I saw using entropy as measure of balance in literature. Other times I saw using $\min{\{c_i\}}/\max{\{c_i\}}$. I guess it does not really matter. They are usually just used as guidance to check the degree of balance of a data set.

Comment: @Simone, interesting. Other two options can be using `KL distance` or `cross entrpoy` to measure the "distance" of `{c_i}/n` probabilities to `1/k`. For KL distance this should be zero of the data-set is balanced and for `cross entropy` it should be come the log(k) for balanced dataset

Comment: @oak yes all these measures are quite related: if $C$ is the clustering and $Q$ is the balanced clustering: $KL(C||Q) = \log(k) - H(C)$ and the cross-entropy $H(C,Q) = H(P) + KL(C||Q)$.

Comment: Simone's suggestion is referred to as the "Shannon Diversity Index" and is common in ecology research. Here is some more information:
https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/auxillar/shannon.htm

Comment: @JamesBudarz then the term `diversity` is misleading as the coefficient indicates the balance of the data.

Answer (score 12):

Based on the answer of Simone, I wrote this short python code to calculate balance, which works very well for me.

```
def balance(seq):
    from collections import Counter
    from numpy import log
    
    n = len(seq)
    classes = [(clas,float(count)) for clas,count in Counter(seq).items()]
    k = len(classes)
    
    H = -sum([ (count/n) * log((count/n)) for clas,count in classes]) #shannon entropy
    return H/log(k)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: for me, I had to change `.iteritems()` for `.items()` only, then it worked! thanks!

Comment: Python 2 vs 3 I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and looked for some metrics to measure the degree of unbalance in my datasets, but I did not find any. Then, I created one that varies between 0 (perfectly balanced, the number of samples in all categories is the same) and 1 (extremely badly balanced, when the number of samples in all classes, except for one, is 1 and the rest of samples belong to a single class)

The formula is:

$$imbalance = \frac{Max_{samples} - Min_{samples}}{Total_{samples} - nclass}$$

Examples:
For a balanced case $Max_{samples} = Min_{samples}$, then $imbalance =0$

For a three class case ($nclass=3$) having 500, 300 and 100 samples each, we have:

$Max_{samples}=500$, $Min_{samples}=100$, and $Total_{samples} = 900$, then

$imbalance = (500-100)/(900-3) = 0.446$

In an extreme three classes case, we have 500, 1 and 1 samples in each class, then

$Max_{samples}=500$, $Min_{samples}=1$ and $Total_{samples} =502$, then

$imbalance = (500-1)/(502-3) = 1$